# C# MVC Amount of Rows in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, model-view-controller

I have a piece of code below - which is looping through an Excel workbook adding the data to an SQL Database - However the forloop doesn't stop when the data runs out.

```
int rowCount = worksheet.Rows.Count -1;
                for (int i = 3; i < rowCount; i++ ) 
                {
                    Spreadsheet spreadsheetToSave = new Spreadsheet();
                    Estimate estimateToSave = new Estimate();
                    RAA raaToSave = new RAA();
                    spreadsheetToSave.Phases = worksheet.Cells[4, i].Value;
                    spreadsheetToSave.Deliverables = worksheet.Cells[5, i].Value;
                    if (worksheet.Cells[6,i].Value == "Y")
                    {
                        spreadsheetToSave.Scope = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        spreadsheetToSave.Scope = false;
                    }
                    spreadsheetToSave.Description = worksheet.Cells[7, i].Value;
                    //estimateToSave.Estimate1 = Convert.ToDecimal(worksheet.Cells[8, i].Value);
                    //estimateToSave.Estimate2 = Convert.ToDecimal(worksheet.Cells[9, i].Value);
                    //estimateToSave.Estimate3 = Convert.ToDecimal(worksheet.Cells[10, i].Value);
                    estimateToSave.Estimate1 = 1;
                    estimateToSave.Estimate2 = 1;
                    estimateToSave.Estimate3 = 1;
                    spreadsheetToSave.Estimate = estimateToSave;

                    db.Spreadsheet.Add(spreadsheetToSave);
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks :)

Comment: If i know excel right, there is a huge amount of cells even when there is no data. So you would need to check if the data in a cell is empty. If you find a empty cell (And you are sure that all cells are filled for as long as there is data), then you only need to `break;` the for-loop. This automatically exits the entire loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your first two lines of code with this:

```
int rowCount = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 3; i <= rowCount; i++)
```

This loops from row 3 to the last filled row.

Also you should check the rest of your code: as far as is know in

```
worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex]
```

the rowIndex comes first :)